# How to post multiple json from one file with cURL

Tags: json, bash, shell, curl

I have some json data store in one file. Each row of that file is a json message.

Rather than:
`curl -X POST -d '{data:{something}}'`
one by one. I try to use :

```
   while read data
   >do
   >curl -X POST -d @$data
   >done < file
```

However it doesn't work, because shell may thing data is some text without single quote.

Is there anyway I can modify this script?

the error message is something like this

```
curl: (3) [globbing] illegal character in range specification at pos 3

curl: (3) [globbing] illegal character in range specification at pos 3

* getaddrinfo(3) failed for "something"::10
* Couldn't resolve host '"something":'
* Closing connection #1
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host '"something":'
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched brace at pos 20

etc...
```

Comment: Curl `-d` option is trying to read a file, because it has `@`.  Just remove `@`, try it first.

Comment: @Azize I have tried that actually, same error.

Comment: Put the error message here, it will help us.

Comment: @Azize Sure, but like what I said, error message is just like what you get when you you `curl -X POST -d {data:{something}}` rather than`curl -X POST -d '{data:{something}}'`. Without single quote

Comment: Use variable in this way `-d "${data}"`, so it will quote data content. But you need to inform the address to curl also. Make sure you are not missing it.

Comment: @Azize Thank you! it solves!

Answer (score 1):

You need to double quote the shell variable to prevent the shell from performing [word splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Word-Splitting) and [filename expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Filename-Expansion):

```
curl -X POST -d "$data"
```